# Int.tryparse, when inout is a string, will still fill up an array slot

Tags: c#, tryparse

So im following a tutorial and I wanted to mess around with the code myself and use a Int.Tryparse instead of a Int.Parse.

It worked but when I enter a character or string it will still fill up a slot in my array as a "0".

Here's my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("How many employee IDs would you like to register?");



string input = Console.ReadLine();

int length; 

if(int.TryParse(input, out length))
{
    int[] employeeIds = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the employee ID.");
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        int id;
        if(int.TryParse(input2, out id))
        {
            employeeIds[i] = id;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please enter a valid integer number.");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeIds.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ID {i + 1}:  \t{employeeIds[i]}");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input is invalid, please input an integer number.");
}
```

I would like to learn how to prevent it from filling up an array slot with a 0 and only add to it if the input was valid ( an int).

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when parsing fails (i.e. non-parsable string), the iterator (which represents array position) is incremented to the next value, skipping one array position and leaving the default int value of 0 in the skipped position.

You need to fix the flow of control so that this doesn't happen. There are many different ways to fix these kinds of issues. You could change `employeeIds` to `List<int>` and then use a while loop to continue looping until you have the expected number of values.

```
Console.WriteLine("How many employee IDs would you like to register?");



string input = Console.ReadLine();

int length; 

if(int.TryParse(input, out length))
{
    List<int> employeeIds = new List<int>(); // ** changed **

    while (employeeIds.Count < length) // ** changed **
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the employee ID.");
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        int id;
        if(int.TryParse(input2, out id))
        {
            employeeIds.Add(id); // ** changed **
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please enter a valid integer number.");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeIds.Count; i++) // ** changed **
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ID {i + 1}:  \t{employeeIds[i]}");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input is invalid, please input an integer number.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to pay more attention to understanding flow of control and then I wonder if it it might be a good challenge for myself to do what you did but with an array, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do it using an array, you just need to work out how to avoid incrementing `i` in your for loop when the user doesn't input a parseable string. That way the array position won't be skipped. The reason for using the `List` type here is that it gives you a `Count` property that can be used in a while loop to repeat code until the List has enough items, and you can do away with the iterator. It's a bit harder with arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, ill give it a go as a challenge and hopefully learn better that way.